# ImportError: No module named openface in windows 8.1

Tags: python, python-3.6, openfaces

I installed `openface` in a virtual environment by following these steps.

```
git clone https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface
cd openface
python setup.py install
```

It gave me the following output after executing `python setup.py install`

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Users\Haneesh\PycharmProjects\Medium\venv\Lib\site-packages\openface-0.2.1-py3.6.egg-info
```

But when I am importing `openface` in python it is giving the following error

```
(venv) C:\Users\Haneesh\PycharmProjects\Medium\openface>.\util\align-dlib.py .\training-images\ align outerEyesAndNose .\aligned-images\ --size 96
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Haneesh\PycharmProjects\Medium\openface\util\align-dlib.py", line 24, in <module>
    import openface
ImportError: No module named openface
```

I tried importing openface in python console also, didn't work.

Comment: This appears to be a windows-specific issue. We run OpenFace with Python 3 on Linux without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

`Openface` as it is, gets installed on `python2`. You can see this line

```
python2 setup.py install && \
```

in [the dockerfile](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/master/Dockerfile)

You can however try converting it to python3 with a help of modules like `2to3` or `six`. At the moment, if it's possible, using python2 is the best option.